# allow user to start program again in c?

Tags: c

I have written a program in c. However once the program is finished it stops (duh). Is there a simple script that allows me to let the user start the program over again?

Comment: What's your environment like? Unix, Windows?

Comment: unix, however it should work in windows as well :(

Comment: There's a lot of "why". Let me speculate. Restarting: resets global state, releases memory back to the OS, "fixes" all memory leaks, allows you throw information away once you've used it, and lets you consider only one path, which is simpler than considering two. I'm all for it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use loop (for, while) in the main itself: ( if the program is simple!)

```
main()
{

 while( Exit condition)
 {
  //logic
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char cont_prog = 'n';
do {
    /* main program in here */
    printf("Do you want to start again? (y/n): ");
    cont_prog = getchar();
} while (cont_prog == 'y' || cont_prog == 'Y');
```

Essentially, you want to put you main prog in a loop, asking the user if they want to continue. You have to deal with the user entering in too much data (they type, 'yes', for example) and your buffer being full next time through the loop.

Comment: \m/ for Fry! I realize that this snippet is rather rudimentary, but the user has been vague so I can't give much more than this.

Comment: thanks for the code. however, it prompts me to start again and when i type 'y' it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: You'll have to hit <Enter> after 'y'.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to re-launch the program without exiting (though I can't see why):

1. Save `argv` (and I'll assume that `argv[0]` actually points to your executable, even though that is not guaranteed) if you want the same command line arguments.
2. Consider saving the environment, if you might change it, and also want it to be repeated.
3. `man execv` or `execle`. Just replace the currently running image with a new one that has the same command line

Frankly, looping would be easier, and can have the same semantics if you avoid global state, or arrange to be able to re-set it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but how would you get the user to run that script? Wouldn't it be simpler to have the user simply re-run the program?

Comment: there isn't an easy way to let the user start the script over again?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#define EXECUTABLE ".exe"
#else
#define EXECUTABLE
#endif
int main(void) {
    for (;;) system("executable_in_c" EXECUTABLE);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile this program, rename your old executable to "executable_in_c[.exe]"; rename this one to the name of your old executable ... voila!